# Show custom post category for single post

Tags: posts, categories, customization

I've tried looking for a article that can help but not getting far, I have a custom post;

```
<?php 
  $args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'swatches', 
  'posts_per_page' => 9999, 
  'order' => 'ASC',                               
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
```

And I want to output the title (easy) and the custom post category it relates to e.g. luxury, standard etc. I've added;

```
'taxonomies' => array('swatches-category','swatches-tags')
```

In my functions and can get it to display all of the categories but not the one it relates too.

I'm trying;

```
<?php $terms = get_terms('swatches-category'); echo $term->name; ?>
```

But no success...

Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'swatches-category' ); foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  echo $term->name; } ?>
```

That solved it! :-)